# Vector tile layer over Google Maps or MapKit in iOS?

Tags: google-maps-api, ios, swift

I'm looking for a way to add a vector tile layer instead of the built in raster layer for Google Maps or MapKit in iOS but I can't seem to find anything that isn't a complete replacement like MapBox.  Does this exist or is there a way to render the vector to UIImage (raster) on device.

Answer (score 0):

For vector tiles on a google map, it has been answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733077/228369

Which is basically use the Deck.gl overlay layer-